# MPI running issue using NVIDIA MPS Service on Multi-GPU nodes

Tags: cuda, mpi, nvidia

I am having problem when running MPI codes using NVIDIA MPS Service on multi-GPU nodes.

The system that I am using has 2 K80 GPUs (total of 4 GPUs).

Basically, I first set the GPU mode to exclusive_process:

```
nvidia_smi -c 3
```

Then I start the MPS Service:

```
nvidia-cuda-mps-control -d
```

When I increase the number of processes and run my code I get the following error:

```
 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
```

Here is an example:

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#define __SIZE__ 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    cudaError_t cuda_err = cudaSuccess;
    void *dev_buf;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int my_rank = -1;
    int dev_cnt = 0;
    int dev_id = -1;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    cuda_err = cudaGetDeviceCount(&dev_cnt);
    if (cuda_err != cudaSuccess)
        printf("cudaGET Error--on rank %d %s\n", my_rank, cudaGetErrorString(cuda_err));

    dev_id = my_rank % dev_cnt;

    printf("myrank=%d dev_cnt=%d, dev_id=%d\n", my_rank, dev_cnt, dev_id);

    cuda_err = cudaSetDevice(dev_id);
    if (cuda_err != cudaSuccess)
        printf("cudaSet Error--on rank %d %s\n", my_rank, cudaGetErrorString(cuda_err));

    cuda_err = cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_buf, __SIZE__);
    if (cuda_err != cudaSuccess)
        printf("cudaMalloc Error--on rank %d %s\n", my_rank, cudaGetErrorString(cuda_err))
    else
        printf("cudaMalloc Success++, %d \n", my_rank);


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output for 12 processes:

```
#mpirun -n 12 -hostfile hosts ./hq_test

myrank=0 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=1 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
myrank=2 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=2
myrank=3 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=3
myrank=4 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=5 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
myrank=6 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=2
myrank=7 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=3
myrank=8 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=9 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
myrank=10 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=2
myrank=11 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=3
cudaMalloc Success++, 8
cudaMalloc Success++, 10
cudaMalloc Success++, 0
cudaMalloc Success++, 1
cudaMalloc Success++, 3
cudaMalloc Success++, 7
cudaMalloc Success++, 9
cudaMalloc Success++, 6
cudaMalloc Success++, 4
cudaMalloc Success++, 2
cudaMalloc Success++, 5
cudaMalloc Success++, 11
```

Here is the output for 14 processes:

```
 #mpirun -n 14 -hostfile hosts ./hq_test

myrank=0 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=1 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
myrank=2 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=2
myrank=3 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=3
myrank=4 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=5 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
myrank=6 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=2
myrank=7 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=3
myrank=8 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=9 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
myrank=10 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=2
myrank=11 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=3
myrank=12 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=0
myrank=13 dev_cnt=4, dev_id=1
cudaMalloc Success++, 11
cudaMalloc Success++, 3
cudaMalloc Success++, 7
cudaMalloc Success++, 2
cudaMalloc Success++, 10
cudaMalloc Success++, 6
cudaMalloc Success++, 1
cudaMalloc Success++, 8
cudaMalloc Error--on rank 13 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
cudaMalloc Error--on rank 5 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
cudaMalloc Error--on rank 9 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
cudaMalloc Error--on rank 4 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
cudaMalloc Error--on rank 0 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
cudaMalloc Error--on rank 12 all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
```

Note: I have already tried changing CUDA_DEVICE_MAX_CONNECTIONS value, but it didn't help.

I'd appreciate if you share your thoughts on this with me.

Comment: Did you try set back the gpu mode to default ?

Comment: Why should I do it with the MPS service enabled? I have done it though, and still had the same problem.

Comment: The [MPS documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) explicitly recommends that the GPUs exposed to the MPS server should be set to EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS.  Refer to section 2.3.1.2

Comment: I'd recommend you include the MPS server log for the failing case.  Edit it into your question.  Also indicate which CUDA version you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on information (MPS server log) in the cross-posting [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/965600/cuda-programming-and-performance/mpi-running-issue-using-nvidia-mps-service-on-multi-gpu-nodes/?offset=5#4977231) the server log in this case indicates a known issue which is covered in the [MPS Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf) section 4.4:

> Memory allocation API calls (including context creation) may fail with the following
>   message in the server log: MPS Server failed to create/open SHM segment.
>   Comments: This is most likely due to exhausting the file descriptor limit on your
>   system. Check the maximum number of open file descriptors allowed on your
>   system and increase if necessary. We recommend setting it to 16384 and higher.
>   Typically this information can be checked via the command ‘ulimit –n’; refer to your
>   operating system instructions on how to change the limit.